# Contradicting Errors?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

So I'm trying to edit a csv file by writing to a temporary file and eventually replacing the original with the temp file. I'm going to have to edit the csv file multiple times so I need to be able to reference it. I've never used the NamedTemporaryFile command before and I'm running into a lot of difficulties. The most persistent problem I'm having is writing over the edited lines.

This part goes through and writes over rows unless specific values are in a specific column and then it just passes over.

I have this:

```
office = 3
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

with open(inFile, "rb") as oi, temp:
    r = csv.reader(oi)
    w = csv.writer(temp)

    for row in r:
        if row[office] == "R00" or row[office] == "ALC" or row[office] == "RMS":
            pass
        else:
            w.writerow(row)
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "H:\jcatoe\Practice Python\pract.py", line 86, in <module>
  cleanOfficeCol()
File "H:\jcatoe\Practice Python\pract.py", line 63, in cleanOfficeCol
  for row in r:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

So I searched for that error and the general consensus was that "rb" needs to be "rt" so I tried that and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "H:\jcatoe\Practice Python\pract.py", line 86, in <module>
  cleanOfficeCol()
File "H:\jcatoe\Practice Python\pract.py", line 67, in cleanOfficeCol
  w.writerow(row)
File "C:\Users\jcatoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tempfile.py", line 483, in func_wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I'm confused because the errors seem to be saying to do the opposite thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [tempfile docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) you'll see that by default it's opening the file in `'w+b'` mode. If you take a closer look at your errors, you'll see that you're getting one on read, and one on write. What you need to be doing is making sure that you're opening your input and output file in the same mode.

You can do it like this:

```
import csv
import tempfile

office = 3
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

with open(inFile, 'r') as oi, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, mode='w') as temp:
    reader = csv.reader(oi)
    writer = csv.writer(temp)

    for row in reader:
        if row[office] == "R00" or row[office] == "ALC" or row[office] == "RMS":
            pass
        else:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!